# Can we use "fury" to refer to a large crowd?

Tags: word-usage

Can we use "fury" to refer to a large crowd? As in this sentence:

> There was a **fury** of people around the crashed building after the bombardment.

Comment: I think you heard *flurry*, rather than *fury*; in that case, it didn't mean "large crowd", it meant "handful of people moving around quickly", same as in "snow flurry".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't correct usage in a technical sense, and is not a standard idiom. However, in written English it's not uncommon to use words in a metaphorical or evocative sense, to create a feeling that may actually be more true-to-life then a simply accurate description. If you simply said "a large crowd of people", it doesn't tell you anything about how they are acting -- "a fury of people" makes it clear that the crowd is angry and roiling. It's critical with this type of writing to keep it unambiguous -- if you just said "a fury" instead of "a fury of people", it would be unclear what is actually happening.